# Flag- is there a way to allow users to only flag themselves?

Tags: flags

I'm on Drupal 7 with Flag 2.0 (beta9).  The flag module provides a checkbox option for user flags, **Users may flag themselves**.  However, I would like to allow users to *only* flag themselves.  In other words, I want to give each user an on/off switch as a flag, but each user should only be able to toggle the switch for herself.

What I am trying to do: I have some options users select at registration (are you interested in A?  B?  C?  etc.)  These are checkboxes.  I want to give users an easy way to change these options after registering.  If I send them to the edit account screen, they get the option to change their password, e-mail address, etc., which is too much.  I was thinking of using flags to do this (with a rule that triggers to *Set a data value* when the user is flagged/unflagged), but it is crucial that users only be able to change their own values.

Comment: Is there a way to use a node flag instead?  Out of the box, there you can restrict it to a node type and also to content only owned by the user (or not).  So if you have the equivalent of a content profile set up in d7, you would be able to set it up so a flag was restricted to that type of content and only to the node owner, which might accomplish what you are after.

Comment: It's a pity that for profile2 user profiles this is not an option, as there is no "Flag access by entity ownership".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a way to use a node flag instead? Out of the box, there you can restrict it to a node type and also to content only owned by the user (or not).

So if you have the equivalent of a content profile set up in d7, you would be able to set it up so a flag was restricted to that type of content and only to the node owner, which might accomplish what you are after.

Comment: Thanks!  I have a special node that is automatically created on account registration, one per user, (via Rules) for other reasons, so I can use this.